# Independent timer in android

Tags: android, timer

I am trying to make a simple game in android. I need to make a timer which can be independent of system time. To make sure that user changes of system time doesn't influence the game timer. I need an idea, about how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your question? Have you tried anything?

Comment: A similar question was answered here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615231/get-device-and-user-independent-time-in-android

Comment: It's not for me. I can't connect to the internet in my aplication. Sorry if my question isn't correct (my english is so bad and it's my fist question on this forum). try to explain. There is some task, which must be runned after 1 hour. And timer must show currect time after reboot device even. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) for this.

Comment: I must keep it works when application is not running. And restore correct value when application runs back.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486162/android-how-to-use-a-timer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877417/how-to-set-a-timer-in-android