# how to set request time out exception

Tags: android

this is my code below which get xml response from server how do i set request time out timer in this code?? my application return exception if server not responding hw do i set  timer in this code below so if server not response in 15 second exception call

```
public static   String[][] AgAppXMLParser( String parUrl) {



    String _node,_element;
    String[][] xmlRespone = null;
    try {

            String url = www.xyz.com;
            URL finalUrl = new URL(url);    


            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(finalUrl.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList list=doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
            _node=new String();
            _element = new String();
            xmlRespone = new String[list.getLength()][2];

            //this "for" loop is used to parse through the
            //XML document and extract all elements and their
            //value, so they can be displayed on the device

            for (int i=0;i<list.getLength();i++)
                {
                    Node value=list.item(i).      getChildNodes().item(0);
                    _node=list.item(i).getNodeName();
                    _element=value.getNodeValue();
                    xmlRespone[i][0] = _node;
                    xmlRespone[i][1] = _element;

                }//end for

        }//end try











    catch (Exception e)
    {
      flag=false;
      Log.e(LOG_TAG, "CONNECTION ERROR   SERVER NOT RESPONDING", e);
    } 



    return xmlRespone;         

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to implement **Timer**...see below reference links...

[How to set a timer in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877417/how-to-set-a-timer-in-android)

[Android: how to use a timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486162/android-how-to-use-a-timer)

[Timer in Android](http://custardbelly.com/blog/2010/10/01/timers-in-android/)

Hope this will help you...

Comment: plese tell e how i a dd timer in my code which use dom xml parsing with url not anyy http connection make